# How does pymc3 posterior simulation work in this simple case without having the full conditional distributions?

Tags: bayesian, inference, simulation, gibbs, pymc

I'm trying to estimate the posterior distribution of the gamma parameters alpha and beta given that my data comes from a gamma distribution and the priors I chose come from two uniform distributions.
I am using the pymc3 library.

```
with pm.Model() as model:
     
    alpha= pm.Uniform('alpha', lower=8, upper=16)
    beta= pm.Uniform('beta', lower=0.01, upper=0.1)
    observed_data = pm.Gamma('observed_data', alpha=alpha, beta=beta, observed=df.values)
    
with model:
    trace = pm.sample(draws=60, chains=50, tune=100, 
                      discard_tuned_samples=True)
```

However I am not able to understand the theory behind it.

It appears that in MCMC methods we are building long chains in order to take "indipendent" draws.
I studied that in Gibbs sampling for example if X and Y have to be simulated, X|Y is simulated and then Y|X, many times. In this case I understand why I need a long chain.

However in this case I only know the distribution of Gamma|alpha,beta and I don't have the full conditional distributions.

Therefore, why do I need exactly a long chain, if I am just sampling from two prior distributions and then use these values to compute the likelihood?
Am I missing something?

Thank you very much for your patience!